# Win 2012 - Create new NIC team only shows me virtual NICs, not the physical NICs, why?

Tags: windows-server-2012, nic, bonding

I am setting up a new win2012 server with NIC teaming.
The server has two physical NICs and I want to create one NIC team in the management OS that uses both NICs.

My problem is that when I installed the Hyper-V role it asked which NICs should be used for Hyper-V and it showed me both physical NICs so I selected both.  After installing the HV role I now have two physical NICs and two virtual NICs.

When I go into the management OS and try to create a NIC team it only shows me the two virtual NICs. Should I delete these virtual NICs and set my physical NICs back to their original configuration and then try to create the NICs team?

My hyper-V network configuration is simple.
I want one NIC team in the management OS using both physical NICs.
I will have one virtual switch with three virtual machines and the management OS all connected to it. I want all machines to talk to each other as well as the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.
I installed a test server with win 2012 and this time I set up my NIC team before I installed the hyper-v role. After installing the HV role it correctly set up the vNICs and vSwitch using the nic team.

I then looked at all of this configuration to understand what I needed to change on the other server to set it up the way I needed.

Actually all I needed to do was to delete the vNICs that were created for each of my physical NICs, then create the NIC team, then set the switch to use this NIC team,
and finally create a vNIC for the management OS.

This topic can be closed.